# Ajax post request in Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am currently trying to call an ajax request from a JavaScript onchange handler to call a Spring MVC controller. I believe the way I am currently calling the URL in my view is wrong since I get an **404 error** on the browser when the event is triggered and call for url. Can anyone shine some light if I have everything setup correctly?

Here is my code:

```
@Controller
public class DataTableController 
{     
    @RequestMapping(value = "/table", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Model model) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException 
    {
        List<String> gpnList = new ArrayList<GPN>();
        gpnList.add("GPN-1"); gpnList.add("GPN-2"); gpnList.add("GPN-3"); 
        model.addAttribute("gpnList", mapper.writeValueAsString(gpnList)); 
        return "index"; //name of my view
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getsector", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String getSector(@RequestParam("market")String market) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException
    {
        List<String> sectors = new ArrayList<String>();
        sectors.add("Auto"); sectors.add("Industrial"); sectors.add("Analog");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(sectors);
    }
}
```

Jquery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    document.getElementById("markets").onchange =  function()
    { 
        var market = $("select[id='markets'").find('option:selected').text();
        var filters = { "market" : market }
        filters = JSON.stringify(filters);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/getsector",
            type: "POST",
            dataType : 'json',
            contentType : "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(filters),
            success: function(response) 
            {
                console.log("sucess!");
            },
            error: function(e){
                console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The main thing I want to achieve is being able to call my controllers via ajax calls. Any other tips on Spring Controller Mapping and conventions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your a requesting information you should use `GET` requests, not `POST`.

You are mixing `@RequestParam` with a json payload. If you want to receive your filter as a request param it has to go at the url, not as a json payload, using something like:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    document.getElementById("markets").onchange =  function()
    { 
        var market = $("select[id='markets'").find('option:selected').text();

        $.ajax({
            url: "/getsector?market="+market,
            type: "GET",
            success: function(response) 
            {
                console.log("sucess!");
            },
            error: function(e){
                console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            }
        });
    }
}); 

@RequestMapping(value = "/getsector", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getSector(@RequestParam("market")String market) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException
{
  .... your logic.
}
```

On the other hand, if you really want to use `POST` requests with a json payload, you need to use `@RequestBody` at the controller and bind the json object to a bean with the same properties.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getsector", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String getSector(@RequestBody Market market) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException
{
    List<String> sectors = new ArrayList<String>();
    sectors.add("Auto"); sectors.add("Industrial"); sectors.add("Analog");
    return sectors;
}


public class Market
{
  String market;

  //getter and setter...
}
```

Bear in mind your javascript is wrong as well, you are using `JSON.stringify` twice.

If you use `@ResponseBody` and spring is configured fine it will make the serialisation for you when returning the response, so you do not have to do it manually.

This code has not been tested, it is just for you to get an idea.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think I will change to using GET for loading my chain of drop down lists.

Comment: Another question if you don't mind, if I have multiple categories of search criterias (markets, sectors, and products), would that be just one Model (filters model), or do I have to create individual models for each one?

Comment: If they do not have the same properties I would go for splinting it up, using a model for every filter category. You can then create a generic one. If you put all together and then, at some point, you only need to filter by sector you are going to drag all other unnecessary properties.